# Wordpress custom field - show image

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, field

I am creating a menu for an Indian restaurant, [The Curry Lounge](http://currylounge.harrisonprice.co.uk/menu). I want to show the vegetarian symbol next to the title (as shown) if it is actually a vegetarian dish.

I have tried to look for a way to do this in custom fields but have had no luck in doing so. I have created a custom field within one of my posts and called it "hass_veg" and in the menu_page_template of my theme I have the following code where I want it to be placed:

```
<?php if ( $hass_veg <> 'Y' ) { ?>
<img src="http://www.tesco.com/wine/UIAssets/I/Sites/Retail/Wine/Online/Product/IsVegetarian.gif" alt="Vegetarian" height="30" width="30">   
<?php } ?>
```

I have deduced that when I put the "Y" in, the image appears on the page.

Can anyone help me at all?

Comment: Use HTML and CSS? `class=veg`

Comment: You need to be more specific. This sounds like a simple `if ($vegetarian) { echo "<img src='/vegetarian.jpg' />; }` to me

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet:

```
    .cufon-canvas{
         background: url('path_to_your_image_goes_here');
}
```

Or whatever class name you choose to give the div next to the vegetarian items. I'd add the image in the stylesheet so you (and others) don't have to dig through the php to change it.